# Guard / Minitest fails - 'capybara is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest, guard

I guard I tried to run all tests - wanted to see which ones still fail.  I get this:

> ```
> capybara is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
> ```

Did some searching and nothing obvious beside the fact I am NOT using capybara in my app and the gem is not installed.

Full output:

```
18:05:09 - INFO - Run all
18:05:09 - INFO - Running: all tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    30: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    29: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    27: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    26: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    25: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    24: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    23: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:33:in `perform'
    22: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:39:in `run'
    21: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `load_tests'
    20: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `each'
    19: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.4/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `block in load_tests'
    18: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    17: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    16: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    15: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    14: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    13: from /Users/aximus/Development/oilfieldtracker/test/system/tag_categories_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    11: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    10: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     9: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     8: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     7: from /Users/aximus/Development/oilfieldtracker/test/application_system_test_case.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     5: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     4: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     3: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     2: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
     1: from /Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/system_test_case.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/aximus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': capybara is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to run a system test - System tests use Capybara, hence it's required.

/Users/aximus/Development/oilfieldtracker/test/system/tag_categories_test.rb

Comment: One of those can't figure it out until right after posting the question ‍♂️. I have been focusing on controller tests etc. and had not run a full test for a while.  Think I must have had the gem installed sometime in the past.